# Get absolute path for MSTest Out folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest

I have a test with the following attribute:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"SampleData\do12.vas.pdws.xls")]
```

When I run the test, my xls file is copied to "TestResults\User Date\Out" folder.

How can I determine the absolute path to this folder from within the test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this

```
[TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@"SampleData\do12.vas.pdws.xls")]
    public void TestGetCardNumbers()
    {

        var controller = new MainController();
        var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();

        string assemblyFile = (new System.Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
        string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assemblyFile);
        path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(path);
        controllerContext.Setup(cc => cc.HttpContext.Session["XlFileUpload"]).Returns(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "do12.vas.pdws.xls"));
```